# Laravel 4 Auth::Attempt

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel. I have an existing app built in CodeIgniter then I want to migrate it to laravel. I'm using laravel 4.

My problem is my `Auth::attempt()` always return `false`.

I have an existing `DB` then I have a table `users`.

My question is do I need to run the migrate to create a new table or I can used the existing table?

here is my table:

```
------------------------------------
-- UserName | Password   | Active --
-- sample   | samplepass | 1      --
------------------------------------
```

the `samplepass` is encrypted using the `Hash::make('samplepass');`

here is my code:

```
$credentials = array(
  'UserName' => Input::get('username'),
  'Password' => Input::get('password'),
  'Active' => 1
);

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
   // redirect to dashboard
} else {
   // return to login page with message
}
```

The output is always return to login page.

I didn't change anything on the `config/auth.php` file

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you haven't hashed your password. Laravel `Auth::attempt()` always hashed your password before match with your database password

```
$password = Hash::make('samplepass');
```

More info: http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords